# how to make navbar element in the center of the row?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```css
.container > ul li {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar2">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="resume.html">PB</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="cen">
               
     <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Resume </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Training Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my code.I dont understand how to do this.actually i try all prevoius answer which are posted in here but those are not helpful to me.plz anyone help me..thanks in  advance.

Comment: OR `.container > .navbar-collapse ul li { ` OR `.container ul.nav li {`

Comment: yes, I am using bootstrap.

Comment: try this `.navbar-collapse  { display: flex;
    justify-content: center;}`

Comment: @Roy 1st one is working when window size is small but 2nd one is not working when window size is normal

Comment: first of all include bootstrap css